# Something went wrong i could not able to fine out

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

```
ComponentInfo{com.org.icube.addmap/com.org.icube.addmap.MapHomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 8115000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I can see above two errors in the log cat

Here are the application files

java file

```
package com.org.icube.addmap;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class MapHomeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_home);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

 private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.mapview)).getMap();


            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

In the above java file i tried using Map and SupportMapFragment 
But still there is no different in the error 
 And the follwing is the XML file which i have used

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.org.icube.addmap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.org.icube.addmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.org.icube.addmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MapHomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="****MY_API_KEY***" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me to get out of this bug , Thanks in advance

Comment: copy `8115000` and paste at `@integer/google_play_services_version`

Comment: Still not workig.getting same error

Comment: don't import `google_play_services` lib project into `workspace` rather provide reference direct from `SDK` b'coz this error come when have latest update sdk and have old `google_play_services` in `workspace`

Comment: We are doing same Kishore

Comment: just change this line android:name="com.google.android.maps.gms.version" to this android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest file, instead of

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

use this,

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```